# Onclick vs addEventListener

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

I'm little confusing by using "onclick" "onmousedown" as a property of HTML elements.

Such as:

```
<button onclick="my_JS_function()"></button>
```

or

```
<div onmousedown="my_another_JS_funciton"></div>
```

But some people tell that only "proper" way of adding "listeners" are by

```
document.getElementById("my_id").addEventListener("onclick", my_JS_function, false);
```

What is the more "proper" more supported way of doing that?

Answer (score 12):

if you already know function and element is part of html i.e. not get added dynamically than its good that you add function inline rather than using extra method call like "addEventListener"

**Another thing to note**

While **onclick works in all browsers**, addEventListener does not work in older versions of Internet Explorer, which uses attachEvent instead.

**OnClick** is a **DOM Level 0** property. **AddEventListener** is part of the **DOM Level 2** definition. Read about this : http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html

inline event handlers added as HTML tag attributes, for example:

```
 <a href="gothere.htm" onlick="alert('Bye!')">Click me!</a>
```

The above techniques are simple but have certain **disadvantages**: they allow you to have just one event handler per element. In addition, with inline event handlers you get very poor separation of JavaScript code from HTML markup.

```
document.getElementById("my_id").addEventListener("onclick", my_JS_function, false);
```

**Advatange of this** : you can add multiple event handler. also separte html and javascript code

For more detail you can read this : [**Adding an Event Handler**](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/addeventlistenerattachevent.htm)

Comment: and when debugging or maintaining such app, its handler is logically associated with the button, as it's declared inline. In this case, inline declaration makes implementation and maintenance easy. There's no need to figure out whether there're other events attached to it. Please explain again, in this scenario, what's the advantage of separating html and javascript?

Answer (score 4):

The latter (`addEventListener()`) is the best way, as you can attach multiple events of the same type to the same element.

By assigning to `onclick`, etc, you will overwrite existing handlers.

Comment: But I can do a function which call other functions... to circumvent the problem of "onclick".

Comment: @alex  in jquery addEventListener() gives error , Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventListener' ?? what to do?

Comment: @simmisimmi If you have a question, you can [ask it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).