# onclick attribute vs onclick in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Why the difference?

document.getElementById('click').onclick = a.replaceChild(c,b) --- replaces the element without me clicking the button

but onclick="a.replaceChild(c,b)" --- replaces the element only after the button is clicked

```
<div id="container">
<p id="welcome">no greetings yet</p>
<p id="products">oreo ice-cream</p>
</div>

<button id="click" **onclick="a.replaceChild(c,b)"**>CHANGE</button>

    <script>

        var a = document.getElementById('container');

        var b = document.getElementById('welcome');

        var c = document.createElement('h2');
        c.id = 'new';
        c.innerHTML = "WELCOME";

        **document.getElementById('click').onclick = a.replaceChild(c,b);**

    </script>
```

Comment: because you call the method and what it returns is assigned to the event listener...

Comment: What is `onclick="a.replaceChild(c,b)` here?

Comment: `replaceChild()` is a javascript function called on container div (`a`). It replace `b` with `c` that means `<p id="welcome">..</p>` replaced by `<h2 id="new">...</h2>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html onclick attribute vs script's onclick event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819916/html-onclick-attribute-vs-scripts-onclick-event-listener)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

You don't include the parentheses: you'd assign a parameterless function like `document.getElementById('foo')=bar;`, not like `bar()`.

The way you're assigning it now actually runs it, which means you're assigning the return value from that function, not its name.

The parameters make it slightly trickier than just naming the function without parentheses.

`document.getElementById("click").onclick = function(c, b){return a.replacechild(c,b);}`

This'll do what you're looking for. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1axberz2/5/)

jQuery's `.click()` is a good alternative if you're interested in solutions that aren't pure basic javascript. Another may be [adding an event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp) instead [in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135126/onclick-vs-addeventlistener).

Answer (score 0):

"document.getElementById('click').onclick" is just returning the state onClick whenever that line runs. Probably at page load time.

What you want to do is add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which will listen for a *change* in the .onclick state. Then call your function with that.

This is what the onClick attribute is doing. Its generally advisable to use an event listener so you cna clearly separate your content from your JS logic.